# XML File Upload and Parsing via GWT

Tags: xml, google-app-engine, gwt, file-upload, saxparser

First of all, I search hours on google and SO about that topic and I found nothing helpful.
This could be the reason, that I'm on the wrong way, or I had overseen the solution.

I had an app which uses GWT and the Appengine. A XML File should be uploaded and be parsed by a SAX-Parser and returns an ArrayList with the entries back to the page.

For local testing I removed the Appengine part of the app.
So I had an Setup of GWT, commons-io & commons-fileupload.

So far I created my Entrypoint and a Servlet for handling the file upload. It is possible to return an String representation of the XML file. But I want to extract the information out of the XML file via parsing and display it in my FlexTable. So I want to create an ArrayList with my elements of the XML file and return it to my entrypoint class.

Entrypoint:

```
public class XMLParser implements EntryPoint {

    private static final String UPLOAD_ACTION_URL = GWT.getModuleBaseURL() + "upload";

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("XMLParserLogger");

     private VerticalPanel mainPanel = new VerticalPanel();
     private FlexTable articleFlexTable = new FlexTable();
     private FileUpload fileUpload = new FileUpload();
     private FormPanel form = new FormPanel();


    /**
     * This is the entry point method.
     */
    public void onModuleLoad() {


        fileUpload.setName("uploadFormElement");

        form.setAction(UPLOAD_ACTION_URL);
        form.setEncoding(FormPanel.ENCODING_MULTIPART);
        form.setMethod(FormPanel.METHOD_POST);
        form.add(fileUpload);


        //Table for Articles
        articleFlexTable.setText(0, 0, "ID");
        articleFlexTable.setText(0, 1, "Amount");
        articleFlexTable.setText(0, 2, "Start Amount");
        articleFlexTable.setText(0, 3, "PCT");
        articleFlexTable.setText(0, 4, "Price");
        articleFlexTable.setText(0, 5, "Stock Value");

        mainPanel.add(form);
        mainPanel.add(new Button("Submit", new ClickHandler() {
            public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
                    form.submit();
                }
            }));
        mainPanel.add(articleFlexTable);

                     form.addSubmitCompleteHandler(new FormPanel.SubmitCompleteHandler() {
                         public void onSubmitComplete(SubmitCompleteEvent event) {

                             String xml = event.getResults();
                             logger.info(xml);
                             Window.alert(xml);
                         }
                     });

        RootPanel.get("parser").add(mainPanel);


    }
}
```

Servlet:

```
public class FileUploadServlet extends HttpServlet {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -5897221701350776117L;
    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(FileUploadServlet.class
            .getName());

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        super.doGet(req, resp);
    }

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        // process only multipart requests
        if (ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(req)) {

            ServletInputStream sis = req.getInputStream();

            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(sis));
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;

            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                stringBuilder.append(line);
            }

            bufferedReader.close();

            String xml = stringBuilder.toString();

            log.info(xml);
            resp.setContentType("text/html");
            resp.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_CREATED);
            resp.getWriter().print(xml);
            resp.flushBuffer();

        } else {
            resp.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNSUPPORTED_MEDIA_TYPE,
                    "Request contents type is not supported by the servlet.");
        }
    }
```

web.xml:

```
 <!-- Servlets -->
   <context-param>
    <!-- max size of the upload request -->
    <param-name>maxSize</param-name>
    <param-value>3145728</param-value>
  </context-param>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>uploadServlet</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>net.mybecks.gwt.server.FileUploadServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>uploadServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/xmlparser/upload</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

I tried using libs like gwtupload, upload4gwt, but they don't solve my issues and are not good documented.

So I exactly want to know how I upload an xml file and return a List as callback. The parsing of the file via SAX I already know.

BR,
mybecks

Comment: So what exactly you want to know? How to parse XML? How to send ArrayList from server to entry point? Or your code doesn't work for some reason?

Comment: Okay, I want to know how I excatly upload an xml file to the server und return a list. How parsing this file I know already. I added it to the questions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your code it seems that you already can get the file to the server and get it back. Now the fun part you can't actually send an array list from the server to client. Client is a javascript, it has no idea what is arraylist. So the server will have to put response into some format, and client will have to parse it into its own *ArrayList*. The easiest way to it is to use Json format.

So workflow is:

1. Client submits file.
2. Server is parsing file, and producing JSON output.
3. Client is parsing JSON output using `JsonUtils` and
   [Javascript Overlay Types](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsOverlay.html) (or `JSONObject` as you wish) and is creating `ArrayList` based on it

Comment: So it is possible to do the xml parsing in the entrypoint class, so I don't need to parse the file twice?

Comment: @mybecks Yes it is possible to parse it in entry point class. The problem is, that not all browsers are have support for reading local files and GWT doesn't have a binding for this api by default. Also sometimes parsing XML on the server side and than sending results to the client via JSON might be faster (for example for XML parsing you might need some information which is not available on the client, so client will have to get it somehow or XML is very complex and you need just some chunks of information from it)